# Android getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier()

Tags: android

I'm developing a simple app with two activities in android studio, and i'm trying to pass some resources values from an activity to the other.
Here's a part of my MainActivity.java:

```
int resId= getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier("xml_pers_1", "layout", getPackageName());
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Personaggio.class);
intent.putExtra("personaggio", resId);
startActivity(intent);
```

And here's a part of the activity which have to recive the value:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
int resId  = bundle.getInt("personaggio");
setContentView(resId);
```

And all this works fine. But if in MainActivity I modify the code like this:

```
String mylayout = "xml_pers_1";
int resId= getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(mylayout, "layout", getPackageName());
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Personaggio.class);
intent.putExtra("personaggio", resId);
startActivity(intent);
```

My app crashes!

What can i do?

Thanks

Comment: What is the crash? Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: I don't believe pulling out a string literal into a variable would have that effect. Something else must have changed here.